# Room + ViewModel + LiveData + RecyclerView (MVVM) Part 7 - ADD NOTE ACTIVITY - Android Tutorial crashes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mvvm

I am following the "Room + ViewModel + LiveData + RecyclerView (MVVM) Android Studio Tutorial" from coding in flow on youtube.  I have copied his code where possible however some of the code he used has been deprecated, namely:

```
noteViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);
```

First I tried using the following as suggested in other posts, however this didn't work.

```
noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);
```

Eventually I found this next line worked for me.

```
noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory
            .getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(NoteViewModel.class);
```

This had been working for me, but now I have carried on the tutorials (I am now on part 7) My app is crashing. This occurs when I try to save a new note. I have compared my code to the code provided and the above line is the only difference. Below is the link to tutorial website where you can find the code.

https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/room-viewmodel-livedata-recyclerview-mvvm/part-7-add-note-activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below version is deprecated

```
noteViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);
```

You should use below version instead

```
noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);
```

But to do so, you need to add the right dependencies into build.gradle (app module version)

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0"
```